# Can any root, such as a square root or a cube root, be rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

I've heard of this and most roots are irrational such as $\sqrt{8}$ and $\sqrt[3]{25}$.  So, can *any* of these roots be rational?  I think so as I'm typing this.  I think these are rational: $\sqrt[4]{256}$ and $\sqrt{144}$.  I know that a rational number can be written as two fractions.  Do the last two simplify to get a number that can be written as fractions?  I think so.  I think the third one simplifies to $4$ and the fourth one simplifies to $12$, while I think the first one simplifies to about 2.83 rounded to the nearest hundredth.  Am I on the serious right track?  I really hope this is a good train track that I'm standing on right here as I'm typing this.

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt[4]{256}$ and $\sqrt{144}$ are rational (they're integers). In general, if $m,n$ are positive integers, $\sqrt[m]{n}$ is rational if and only if it's an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers with no bigger common divisors than $1$, and $m,n>1$ are integers.  Suppose
$$
\sqrt[n]{m} = \frac a b.
$$
Then
$$
b^n m = a^n.
$$
Consider prime factorizations of $b$ and $a$:
$$
\left(q_1^{e^1}\cdots q_k^{e_k}\right)^n m = p_1^{f_1}\cdots p_\ell^{f_\ell}.
$$
Since none of $p_1,\ldots,p_\ell$ is a divisor of $\left(q_1^{e^1}\cdots q_k^{e_k}\right)^n$, we must have $p_1^{f_1}\cdots p_\ell^{f_\ell}$ dividing $m$, but that makes the left side bigger than the right side unless $b=1$.  From that we conclude that $a/b$ is an integer.  So it's only when the $n$th root is an integer that the $n$th root is rational.

Perhaps the hard part of the proof is what I haven't yet mentioned: prove that an integer cannot have more than one prime factorization.  That was tacitly used above.  (Maybe one can get by with a somewhat weaker result.)

Comment: A related way of thinking of this, is to see that unique factorization leads to this corollary: If $\frac{a}{b}$ is in lowest terms, then "automatically" $\frac{a^n}{b^n}$ is in lowest terms, and equal to $\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) ^n$. So if $\frac{a^n}{b^n}$ is in lowest terms and equal to integer $m=\frac{m}{1}$, then $b$ is one, and the rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ is actually an integer.